# example of using Woodstox to parse a simple XML

Tags: xml-parsing, woodstox

Can anyone give me an example of using the Woodstox parser to parser an XML file? Or point me to a place where I can look at some examples?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below link would be a good resource to look into to compare the whole parsing thing along with JAXB and their comparisons. The author has also mentioned about the jaxb2 maven plugin to generate xjc sources as part of your build in case you are inclined towards maven.

[xml-unmarshalling-benchmark](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/xml-unmarshalling-benchmark-jaxb-vs.html)